# How To Access My PostgreSQL Server From Another PC Securely?

Tags: postgresql, connectivity

I want to be able to connect from any PC anywhere to my Database.

Host

1. OS: Windows 10
2. PostgreSQL: 12.0

Currently all Tutorials say the same: (Thats what i also did)

1. Change listen_addresses to `listen_addresses = '*'` in the postgresql.conf
2. Add `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` in the pg_hba.conf

But they don't say how to connect from the Client Side and they don't pinpoint how secure it is to do so.

Let's say at the Host I Did the above steps and restarted.
I created a Database called TablesTest.

How do I connect to this database at the Client? How secure is it?

Comment: What client do you want to connect from?  Did you assign a good password to the user?

Comment: @jjanes I want to be able to install postgresql at any PC with pgadmin and then connect to the database(hosted at another PC).

Answer (score 1):

How to connect should be trivial: fill the appropriate values into the pgAdmin dialog (host, port, user, database). If I remember correctly, pgAdmin calls the database "administrative database" or similar.

This is fairly secure, if you want to do better, here are some ideas:

- Use the `scram-sha-256` authentication method rather than `md5`. This requires that you change `password_encryption` to `scram-sha-256` on the server and assign a new password to the user.
- Limit the `pg_hba.conf` entry so that only one user can connect to one database from a single host, for example

  ```
  host databasename username 12.34.56.78/32 scram-sha-256
  ```
- For better security, don't allow remote connections as a superuser.
- For transport security, you can [enable SSL connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html). Without that, the communication between database client and database server is unencrypted.

Comment: Im sry to ask this stupid question but can you "How to connect should be trivial" explain this trivial part what is my host is it my Ip v4 etc..?

Comment: `host` is any name that can be used to establish a TCP connection to the database server machine: host name or IP address. Anything that works with `ping`.